# Increment an enumeration value to the next one

Tags: c#, enums, bit

I have an enumeration like so:

```
   [Flags]
    public enum UserProcessStage : uint
    {
        ShopSelection = 1,
        FillBasket = 2,
        SpecifyShipmentCredentials = 4,
        SpecifyPaymentCredentials = 8,
        OrderComplete = 16
    }
```

Assuming I have a variable whose value is FillBakset (2), what I want to do is be able to increment it to the next value that is defined within the enumeration (SpecifyShipmentCredentials, 4).

The problem is that incrementing it causes its value to be 3 since it is based on an integer, I tried multipliying it by 2 but got a compilation error.

How could I increment an enumeration value to the next one ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get next (or previous) enum value in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642542/how-to-get-next-or-previous-enum-value-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Is there a reason this is designed as a `[Flags]` enum? "Increment to the next state" would make more sense for a regular enum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code. It basically orders the enum by underlying value and then givs you the first enum which is bigger than the one specified. If none found, it will return 0 because of `DefaultIfEmty()`:

```
public static UserProcessStage GetNext(UserProcessStage value)
{
    return (from UserProcessStage val in Enum.GetValues(typeof (UserProcessStage)) 
            where val > value 
            orderby val 
            select val).DefaultIfEmpty().First();
}
```