# Get Next item in Enum and return first if last+1

Tags: c#, enums

I saw [How to get next (or previous) enum value in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642542/how-to-get-next-or-previous-enum-value-in-c-sharp/643438) and was wondering if that could also return the first item if the next item would be (last+1). So imagine:

```
public enum MODE {
    OFF,
    CHANNEL,
    TALKING
}

MODE Mode = MODE.OFF;

Mode = Mode.Next(); // should give me MODE.CHANNEL
Mode = Mode.Next(); // should give me MODE.TALKING
Mode = Mode.Next(); // should give me MODE.OFF
```

Comment: This is *cycling* and it can be done with normal iteration by adding `if` and `Enum.IsDefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add *modulo arithmetics* to *husayt's answer*

[How to get next (or previous) enum value in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642542/how-to-get-next-or-previous-enum-value-in-c-sharp/643438)

Code:

```
public static class Extensions {
  public static T Next<T>(this T src) where T : struct {
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
      throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Argument {0} is not an Enum", 
                                                 typeof(T).FullName));

    T[] Arr = (T[])Enum.GetValues(src.GetType());

    int j = (Array.IndexOf<T>(Arr, src) + 1) % Arr.Length; // <- Modulo % Arr.Length added

    return Arr[j];
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to work:

<16:14:51> "Blu": !acc toggle
<16:14:51> "Dvni": AutoChannelCommander is now CHANNEL
<16:14:52> "Blu": !acc toggle
<16:14:52> "Dvni": AutoChannelCommander is now TALKING
<16:14:53> "Blu": !acc toggle

Comment: @Bluscream: Sorry?

Comment: Nvm, i missed your edit. Now it's working just fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: A good answer, but I'd argue against making this an extension method since you can't make the compiler enforce the rule that it should only apply to enums. So confusingly you can do things like `1.Next()` which will compile just fine but fail at runtime.

Comment: @Matt Burland: you are quite right; in my adaptaion of husayt's answer I've tried to support OP syntax `Mode.Next()`; in case of **C# 7.3** we can put `T : struct, Enum`

Comment: ` in case of C# 7.3 we can put T : struct, Enum` - wasn't aware of that. That's actually pretty awesome. Not being able to do that has been annoying for a long time.

Comment: @Matt Burland: another 7.3 improvement is `where T: Delegate`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be useful:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MODE Mode = MODE.TALKING; //Whatever value;
        int index = (int)Mode;
        index = ++index % 3;
        Mode = (MODE)index;
        Console.WriteLine("Mode value {0} ; index {1}", Mode, index );
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: It is only an idea to implement a new method.